# Reduce array to sum amounts within time period

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have the following code but I am having trouble figuring out how I can recode it to look at payments.time first and only total those within the last 24 hours (86400)

```js
var addr = 't1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU',
  data = [{
    "name": "zelcash",
    "pending": {
      "blocks": [
        "0000000cc8cb614f91c1f2cb97cce10c6fcbcc16a10ed9e209e03b3debafe56e:b7887996c1267949ffcd80773a6512e7df9cce392ba1f76c89f3b5fa974a0c91:99856:t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU.Lana:1529254887651",
        "00000005a9bf4d9b58d031c4868b14645e93a29fa057f3a02547c8cc70ad46e2:7e679e73247e724e707c485dc9111f981e2bf7f19814abadfa7cecfbb897b146:99735:t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU.Del:1529240255922"
      ],
      "confirms": {
        "00000005a9bf4d9b58d031c4868b14645e93a29fa057f3a02547c8cc70ad46e2": "130",
        "0000000cc8cb614f91c1f2cb97cce10c6fcbcc16a10ed9e209e03b3debafe56e": "9"
      }
    },
    "payments": [{
        "time": 1529253343149,
        "txid": "b1f67fd9fee10f16b56e3e8d5cf9385a7bc9526a2e0e3d87474827e12fb76160",
        "shares": 42734.058416500004,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          99688
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 42734.058416500004
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529209541970,
        "txid": "b050e07659adc3bd39cb88a91d1c7bbe8c9bfef082451da5b205598f6a7b5db7",
        "shares": 87605.48433238,
        "paid": 149.85,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          99345
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 87605.48433238
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529125539715,
        "txid": "75b56806a856ecc2a6c1c61d336885150ab0ad337fe6eaadcbc6ec514da8874b",
        "shares": 67039.31083319,
        "paid": 149.85049311,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          98640
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85049311
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 67039.31083319
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529028937339,
        "txid": "ee4d3d3ec4c08d64a378815727ae7044a1456e431a985bc55bc26daa5aee0223",
        "shares": 3104.29760367,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          97823
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 3104.29760367
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529024137173,
        "txid": "c0451e2ad08a720f685ea7c522bf8d634b00e052e5895aa875b9b0feedc27348",
        "shares": 50725.214786690005,
        "paid": 149.84990226,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          97798
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84990226
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 50725.214786690005
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528938335048,
        "txid": "d7a2a8cc32c8d32ca099315ec1a0876217a4327f72c196924b0c1887c5fe7445",
        "shares": 26410.11564011,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          97096
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 26410.11564011
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528913134453,
        "txid": "4d5c9cc4ed088e3254392f323066ebda849a8a7e3f307e0e627d581c4c472d31",
        "shares": 40580.80231319,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96889
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 40580.80231319
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528868733295,
        "txid": "9ce3565134e056c92b0306df7be77e79199db2466a203327ed2d2e08bc9e235d",
        "shares": 6602.56576397,
        "paid": 149.85000464,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96520
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85000464
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 6602.56576397
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528865133212,
        "txid": "60e4d615ab23204ccef61609b228be1421e3ab649a1164ae50f060722b5c31dc",
        "shares": 6928.362205519999,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96461
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 6928.362205519999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528854933095,
        "txid": "eea83530e19e5c31263cfd79492a5af9102451c6b565916554e33fa187a67945",
        "shares": 21489.088447084003,
        "paid": 149.84999999,
        "miners": 2,
        "blocks": [
          96392
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 133.34363659,
          "t1N41CQNY7wnDAEjFCBtfRgASGHBc7XHnZU": 16.5063634
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 19122.01001398,
          "t1N41CQNY7wnDAEjFCBtfRgASGHBc7XHnZU": 2367.078433104
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528834954934,
        "txid": "f6d4eabe2a90545bddb96e687281144d956026a39519920a4b5a8b279de68fb2",
        "shares": 19609.1102692,
        "paid": 149.85045733,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96219
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85045733
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 19609.1102692
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528814554277,
        "txid": "802947af15e475deaed5afd2ff595b59bd17ae2166e70b6fa3a5b1e084d66595",
        "shares": 28021.99010114,
        "paid": 149.850106,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96056
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.850106
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 28021.99010114
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528785753397,
        "txid": "bc2a1d4268dc5ea371b3190c3e491423f3f3ba3e90b97d4bd804ae8b7615f310",
        "shares": 92962.78615252,
        "paid": 149.85010001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          95827
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85010001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 92962.78615252
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528672350183,
        "txid": "c23a481796e55cd238e83a9f29e7f0e6d038ea2cc23c3f7f14f7cae89a0c678f",
        "shares": 2028.6092466999999,
        "paid": 149.85,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94888
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 2028.6092466999999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528669950113,
        "txid": "186bd6824fabb6afeec2f4d012b80d356f53dab33c04b5fdf9b6cc8f7d0c5820",
        "shares": 776.0212537699999,
        "paid": 149.85010001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94862
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85010001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 776.0212537699999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528668150031,
        "txid": "908c4fec156aa4551a42e05289ed0ed98838ff9fd7fba5c7d1246ec7d7087cac",
        "shares": 66284.28441329999,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94858
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 66284.28441329999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528599148167,
        "txid": "9e9da753d046924b182583b3ac65bf7059855a7c973ec1fd67d51ac13c048ea0",
        "shares": 1197.33956242,
        "paid": 149.84995666,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94274
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84995666
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 1197.33956242
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528596748331,
        "txid": "c5efb5e87443c17a8754ce5b9565e388062fe4c3b2040577bfcb5c2e309810b8",
        "shares": 21428.0708466,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94262
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 21428.0708466
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528572147403,
        "txid": "bd3f2b453f11b2065238f28f4240d4aa808d6504d6d95b03e73c64f9435cc0df",
        "shares": 9707.29130202,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94055
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 9707.29130202
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528559547010,
        "txid": "d3d786138d1160ccd541193a30b5c1193c7891e0aaf6a2b9524d79e88ae135d9",
        "shares": 35197.046698520004,
        "paid": 149.85036822,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          93956
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85036822
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 35197.046698520004
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528526546074,
        "txid": "1d3b65c03eece5416b549aacd170f9fa4fa5c37bf96a418b01620398fc798554",
        "shares": 22786.8939854,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          93669
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 22786.8939854
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528502545384,
        "txid": "bc912683a05aac13c6e6f65b6b89bf51e66e072da6d5576c892ba40adc93d1f1",
        "shares": 19795.81189089,
        "paid": 149.85126176,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          93475
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85126176
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 19795.81189089
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528387342482,
        "txid": "f49a81c73629ee723c3c080e392c6273c3a010f1ff8b04cdfd4ffb1d6651ddb4",
        "shares": 13801.18398016,
        "paid": 149.85006379,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92525
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85006379
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 13801.18398016
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528373542146,
        "txid": "ab0f04fa27cf112827a647e81b9669370c91736ebbae24535c75885d2b847a9e",
        "shares": 36476.16667485,
        "paid": 149.85000001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92411
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85000001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 36476.16667485
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528337873333,
        "txid": "5153937d325780b3ed78fe38dd2bab02baefc55d23e049a994bbcd4da84c3b72",
        "shares": 940.4181375700001,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92107
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 940.4181375700001
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528335473504,
        "txid": "03e601161435ca1fa420ee042b589d11624a0e2ad3ff6a57eb95b77a1bd7169b",
        "shares": 13851.424451159999,
        "paid": 149.85,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92092
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 13851.424451159999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528322272892,
        "txid": "ba6c268f93705e86d0a218c180b90600f6472539e52fda3a452fdfea0cf1a4c7",
        "shares": 82079.63046338,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          91973
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 82079.63046338
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528238870764,
        "txid": "7ca39936f3ff8fe53c2f79e21e34d7857adbaefc6e6d1af57cf1cca92957a114",
        "shares": 76737.7005630349,
        "paid": 149.84827801,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          91294
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84827801
        },
        "balances": {
          "t1WtvsMS53Hy2J2AmcnHBZwRVRZPEejmKYh": 0.00162199
        },
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 76736.86994562,
          "t1WtvsMS53Hy2J2AmcnHBZwRVRZPEejmKYh": 0.8306174149000043
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528157268659,
        "txid": "cb0e1868226c90efd00b5cd8fdff2e3b48ef27f07baac212e17e834a2f939977",
        "shares": 55456.70607415,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          90643
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 55456.70607415
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528090066808,
        "txid": "c122dbbbfca258a8dfe07dd685ffc13505a2e97334c56d564fe7b19cbd297121",
        "shares": 20286.36657748,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          90082
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 20286.36657748
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528066666230,
        "txid": "e081bd339f76e95f3fe637abc4b33694cfc7fd3bcf6cd3896a9d57972b2b2e4f",
        "shares": 12740.56517011,
        "paid": 149.84991112,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89883
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84991112
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 12740.56517011
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528046265763,
        "txid": "8155afb7fcd4b9f7a3e31d9621d833a2f27a00101834694fd17ed97d74ff4c3f",
        "shares": 10092.89574236,
        "paid": 149.85020001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89730
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85020001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 10092.89574236
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528034865459,
        "txid": "d801d78f370742ecab69107b10390b7c9982270eed84249bb75edd6771b17c48",
        "shares": 1080.43224556,
        "paid": 149.8504,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89631
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8504
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 1080.43224556
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528034265462,
        "txid": "c4675e5fafd08b81c9a5a2b8c29e90a396a36e9e8ed18e8c728e155d08e8b722",
        "shares": 17724.76201563,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89622
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 17724.76201563
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528012664846,
        "txid": "465fbc8ced6bd1466c7bc18482ff265cfc508dd00deabf29db037290a14fed2c",
        "shares": 13233.20481279,
        "paid": 149.84997922,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89447
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84997922
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 13233.20481279
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1527998264492,
        "txid": "6850c419e97170a4ff60ea7c564a33c726c6445b22434901b5d4cd5d2f3c23b8",
        "shares": 58721.78385429,
        "paid": 149.85027536,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89312
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85027536
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 58721.78385429
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522691664138,
        "txid": "85723d60e454626ac1c7f1333a0d2e0073faba5588868eb87583e517890d8026",
        "shares": 1717.07527153,
        "paid": 149.850023,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          45397
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.850023
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 1717.07527153
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522688663809,
        "txid": "c0a05ef564b660355a7cedc41bb816c804ce6f77559c47fc668b8510ebe2bb17",
        "shares": 15514.524170879999,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          45368
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 15514.524170879999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522638303217,
        "txid": "24c0bfcb3c67a79cffd9830bebc524e50827dd4fefd7316ae26e479cdcea880a",
        "shares": 5678.853654129999,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          44665
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 5678.853654129999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522604440745,
        "txid": "545feed0c5cb9f294ae260b9ec7e33cf5a5d814f32714d2bceb8fbc136f6d8be",
        "shares": 454.36380947,
        "paid": 149.8501,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          44581
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8501
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 454.36380947
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522593827155,
        "txid": "3d6b8ca0d33d644d57a38196fe47d5da228a50061805499807ae311f84adf5c9",
        "shares": 10549.50725814,
        "paid": 149.85012367,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          44575
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85012367
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 10549.50725814
        }
      }
    ]
  }]

var totalAmount =
  data[0].payments.
map(payment => payment.amounts). //get all amount object
map(amounts => amounts[addr]). //get amount from addr
filter(price => price). //filter undefined amount
reduce((first, second) => { //sum amount
  return first + second;
});
totalAmount = totalAmount.toFixed(5);
console.log(totalAmount)
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Comment: Please post a sample output.

Comment: @amrendersingh currently it simply returns 6127.34414 as it totals all the amounts for the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a filter on the time based on the current time minus one day, as shown here:

```js
var addr = 't1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU',
  data = [{
    "name": "zelcash",
    "pending": {
      "blocks": [
        "0000000cc8cb614f91c1f2cb97cce10c6fcbcc16a10ed9e209e03b3debafe56e:b7887996c1267949ffcd80773a6512e7df9cce392ba1f76c89f3b5fa974a0c91:99856:t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU.Lana:1529254887651",
        "00000005a9bf4d9b58d031c4868b14645e93a29fa057f3a02547c8cc70ad46e2:7e679e73247e724e707c485dc9111f981e2bf7f19814abadfa7cecfbb897b146:99735:t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU.Del:1529240255922"
      ],
      "confirms": {
        "00000005a9bf4d9b58d031c4868b14645e93a29fa057f3a02547c8cc70ad46e2": "130",
        "0000000cc8cb614f91c1f2cb97cce10c6fcbcc16a10ed9e209e03b3debafe56e": "9"
      }
    },
    "payments": [{
        "time": 1529253343149,
        "txid": "b1f67fd9fee10f16b56e3e8d5cf9385a7bc9526a2e0e3d87474827e12fb76160",
        "shares": 42734.058416500004,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          99688
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 42734.058416500004
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529209541970,
        "txid": "b050e07659adc3bd39cb88a91d1c7bbe8c9bfef082451da5b205598f6a7b5db7",
        "shares": 87605.48433238,
        "paid": 149.85,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          99345
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 87605.48433238
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529125539715,
        "txid": "75b56806a856ecc2a6c1c61d336885150ab0ad337fe6eaadcbc6ec514da8874b",
        "shares": 67039.31083319,
        "paid": 149.85049311,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          98640
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85049311
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 67039.31083319
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529028937339,
        "txid": "ee4d3d3ec4c08d64a378815727ae7044a1456e431a985bc55bc26daa5aee0223",
        "shares": 3104.29760367,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          97823
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 3104.29760367
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529024137173,
        "txid": "c0451e2ad08a720f685ea7c522bf8d634b00e052e5895aa875b9b0feedc27348",
        "shares": 50725.214786690005,
        "paid": 149.84990226,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          97798
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84990226
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 50725.214786690005
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528938335048,
        "txid": "d7a2a8cc32c8d32ca099315ec1a0876217a4327f72c196924b0c1887c5fe7445",
        "shares": 26410.11564011,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          97096
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 26410.11564011
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528913134453,
        "txid": "4d5c9cc4ed088e3254392f323066ebda849a8a7e3f307e0e627d581c4c472d31",
        "shares": 40580.80231319,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96889
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 40580.80231319
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528868733295,
        "txid": "9ce3565134e056c92b0306df7be77e79199db2466a203327ed2d2e08bc9e235d",
        "shares": 6602.56576397,
        "paid": 149.85000464,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96520
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85000464
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 6602.56576397
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528865133212,
        "txid": "60e4d615ab23204ccef61609b228be1421e3ab649a1164ae50f060722b5c31dc",
        "shares": 6928.362205519999,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96461
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 6928.362205519999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528854933095,
        "txid": "eea83530e19e5c31263cfd79492a5af9102451c6b565916554e33fa187a67945",
        "shares": 21489.088447084003,
        "paid": 149.84999999,
        "miners": 2,
        "blocks": [
          96392
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 133.34363659,
          "t1N41CQNY7wnDAEjFCBtfRgASGHBc7XHnZU": 16.5063634
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 19122.01001398,
          "t1N41CQNY7wnDAEjFCBtfRgASGHBc7XHnZU": 2367.078433104
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528834954934,
        "txid": "f6d4eabe2a90545bddb96e687281144d956026a39519920a4b5a8b279de68fb2",
        "shares": 19609.1102692,
        "paid": 149.85045733,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96219
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85045733
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 19609.1102692
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528814554277,
        "txid": "802947af15e475deaed5afd2ff595b59bd17ae2166e70b6fa3a5b1e084d66595",
        "shares": 28021.99010114,
        "paid": 149.850106,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96056
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.850106
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 28021.99010114
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528785753397,
        "txid": "bc2a1d4268dc5ea371b3190c3e491423f3f3ba3e90b97d4bd804ae8b7615f310",
        "shares": 92962.78615252,
        "paid": 149.85010001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          95827
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85010001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 92962.78615252
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528672350183,
        "txid": "c23a481796e55cd238e83a9f29e7f0e6d038ea2cc23c3f7f14f7cae89a0c678f",
        "shares": 2028.6092466999999,
        "paid": 149.85,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94888
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 2028.6092466999999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528669950113,
        "txid": "186bd6824fabb6afeec2f4d012b80d356f53dab33c04b5fdf9b6cc8f7d0c5820",
        "shares": 776.0212537699999,
        "paid": 149.85010001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94862
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85010001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 776.0212537699999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528668150031,
        "txid": "908c4fec156aa4551a42e05289ed0ed98838ff9fd7fba5c7d1246ec7d7087cac",
        "shares": 66284.28441329999,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94858
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 66284.28441329999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528599148167,
        "txid": "9e9da753d046924b182583b3ac65bf7059855a7c973ec1fd67d51ac13c048ea0",
        "shares": 1197.33956242,
        "paid": 149.84995666,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94274
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84995666
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 1197.33956242
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528596748331,
        "txid": "c5efb5e87443c17a8754ce5b9565e388062fe4c3b2040577bfcb5c2e309810b8",
        "shares": 21428.0708466,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94262
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 21428.0708466
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528572147403,
        "txid": "bd3f2b453f11b2065238f28f4240d4aa808d6504d6d95b03e73c64f9435cc0df",
        "shares": 9707.29130202,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94055
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 9707.29130202
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528559547010,
        "txid": "d3d786138d1160ccd541193a30b5c1193c7891e0aaf6a2b9524d79e88ae135d9",
        "shares": 35197.046698520004,
        "paid": 149.85036822,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          93956
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85036822
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 35197.046698520004
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528526546074,
        "txid": "1d3b65c03eece5416b549aacd170f9fa4fa5c37bf96a418b01620398fc798554",
        "shares": 22786.8939854,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          93669
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 22786.8939854
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528502545384,
        "txid": "bc912683a05aac13c6e6f65b6b89bf51e66e072da6d5576c892ba40adc93d1f1",
        "shares": 19795.81189089,
        "paid": 149.85126176,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          93475
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85126176
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 19795.81189089
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528387342482,
        "txid": "f49a81c73629ee723c3c080e392c6273c3a010f1ff8b04cdfd4ffb1d6651ddb4",
        "shares": 13801.18398016,
        "paid": 149.85006379,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92525
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85006379
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 13801.18398016
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528373542146,
        "txid": "ab0f04fa27cf112827a647e81b9669370c91736ebbae24535c75885d2b847a9e",
        "shares": 36476.16667485,
        "paid": 149.85000001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92411
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85000001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 36476.16667485
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528337873333,
        "txid": "5153937d325780b3ed78fe38dd2bab02baefc55d23e049a994bbcd4da84c3b72",
        "shares": 940.4181375700001,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92107
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 940.4181375700001
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528335473504,
        "txid": "03e601161435ca1fa420ee042b589d11624a0e2ad3ff6a57eb95b77a1bd7169b",
        "shares": 13851.424451159999,
        "paid": 149.85,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92092
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 13851.424451159999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528322272892,
        "txid": "ba6c268f93705e86d0a218c180b90600f6472539e52fda3a452fdfea0cf1a4c7",
        "shares": 82079.63046338,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          91973
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 82079.63046338
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528238870764,
        "txid": "7ca39936f3ff8fe53c2f79e21e34d7857adbaefc6e6d1af57cf1cca92957a114",
        "shares": 76737.7005630349,
        "paid": 149.84827801,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          91294
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84827801
        },
        "balances": {
          "t1WtvsMS53Hy2J2AmcnHBZwRVRZPEejmKYh": 0.00162199
        },
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 76736.86994562,
          "t1WtvsMS53Hy2J2AmcnHBZwRVRZPEejmKYh": 0.8306174149000043
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528157268659,
        "txid": "cb0e1868226c90efd00b5cd8fdff2e3b48ef27f07baac212e17e834a2f939977",
        "shares": 55456.70607415,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          90643
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 55456.70607415
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528090066808,
        "txid": "c122dbbbfca258a8dfe07dd685ffc13505a2e97334c56d564fe7b19cbd297121",
        "shares": 20286.36657748,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          90082
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 20286.36657748
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528066666230,
        "txid": "e081bd339f76e95f3fe637abc4b33694cfc7fd3bcf6cd3896a9d57972b2b2e4f",
        "shares": 12740.56517011,
        "paid": 149.84991112,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89883
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84991112
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 12740.56517011
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528046265763,
        "txid": "8155afb7fcd4b9f7a3e31d9621d833a2f27a00101834694fd17ed97d74ff4c3f",
        "shares": 10092.89574236,
        "paid": 149.85020001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89730
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85020001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 10092.89574236
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528034865459,
        "txid": "d801d78f370742ecab69107b10390b7c9982270eed84249bb75edd6771b17c48",
        "shares": 1080.43224556,
        "paid": 149.8504,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89631
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8504
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 1080.43224556
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528034265462,
        "txid": "c4675e5fafd08b81c9a5a2b8c29e90a396a36e9e8ed18e8c728e155d08e8b722",
        "shares": 17724.76201563,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89622
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 17724.76201563
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528012664846,
        "txid": "465fbc8ced6bd1466c7bc18482ff265cfc508dd00deabf29db037290a14fed2c",
        "shares": 13233.20481279,
        "paid": 149.84997922,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89447
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84997922
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 13233.20481279
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1527998264492,
        "txid": "6850c419e97170a4ff60ea7c564a33c726c6445b22434901b5d4cd5d2f3c23b8",
        "shares": 58721.78385429,
        "paid": 149.85027536,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89312
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85027536
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 58721.78385429
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522691664138,
        "txid": "85723d60e454626ac1c7f1333a0d2e0073faba5588868eb87583e517890d8026",
        "shares": 1717.07527153,
        "paid": 149.850023,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          45397
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.850023
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 1717.07527153
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522688663809,
        "txid": "c0a05ef564b660355a7cedc41bb816c804ce6f77559c47fc668b8510ebe2bb17",
        "shares": 15514.524170879999,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          45368
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 15514.524170879999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522638303217,
        "txid": "24c0bfcb3c67a79cffd9830bebc524e50827dd4fefd7316ae26e479cdcea880a",
        "shares": 5678.853654129999,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          44665
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 5678.853654129999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529257180996,
        "txid": "545feed0c5cb9f294ae260b9ec7e33cf5a5d814f32714d2bceb8fbc136f6d8be",
        "shares": 454.36380947,
        "paid": 149.8501,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          44581
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8501
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 454.36380947
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529267356115,
        "txid": "3d6b8ca0d33d644d57a38196fe47d5da228a50061805499807ae311f84adf5c9",
        "shares": 10549.50725814,
        "paid": 149.85012367,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          44575
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85012367
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 10549.50725814
        }
      }
    ]
  }]

var oneDayAgoInSeconds = new Date(Date.now()-1).getTime();

var totalAmount =
  data[0].payments.filter(payment => payment.time >= oneDayAgoInSeconds).
map(payment => payment.amounts). //get all amount object
map(amounts => amounts[addr]). //get amount from addr
filter(price => price). //filter undefined amount
reduce((first, second) => { //sum amount
  return first + second;
}, 0);
totalAmount = totalAmount.toFixed(5);
console.log(totalAmount)
```

NOTE: I also added a '0' after the return of your reduce, this prevents a `TypeError: reduce of empty array with no initial value` when no elements are returned after the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Add a filter before to get the payments done in last 24 hours, before you start the process:

```
.filter(payment => payment.time > Date.now() - 24*60*60*1000)
```

`Date.now() - 24*60*60*1000` will give the unixtime of 24 hours before.

```js
var addr = 't1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU',
  data = [{
    "name": "zelcash",
    "pending": {
      "blocks": [
        "0000000cc8cb614f91c1f2cb97cce10c6fcbcc16a10ed9e209e03b3debafe56e:b7887996c1267949ffcd80773a6512e7df9cce392ba1f76c89f3b5fa974a0c91:99856:t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU.Lana:1529254887651",
        "00000005a9bf4d9b58d031c4868b14645e93a29fa057f3a02547c8cc70ad46e2:7e679e73247e724e707c485dc9111f981e2bf7f19814abadfa7cecfbb897b146:99735:t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU.Del:1529240255922"
      ],
      "confirms": {
        "00000005a9bf4d9b58d031c4868b14645e93a29fa057f3a02547c8cc70ad46e2": "130",
        "0000000cc8cb614f91c1f2cb97cce10c6fcbcc16a10ed9e209e03b3debafe56e": "9"
      }
    },
    "payments": [{
        "time": 1529253343149,
        "txid": "b1f67fd9fee10f16b56e3e8d5cf9385a7bc9526a2e0e3d87474827e12fb76160",
        "shares": 42734.058416500004,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          99688
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 42734.058416500004
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529209541970,
        "txid": "b050e07659adc3bd39cb88a91d1c7bbe8c9bfef082451da5b205598f6a7b5db7",
        "shares": 87605.48433238,
        "paid": 149.85,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          99345
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 87605.48433238
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529125539715,
        "txid": "75b56806a856ecc2a6c1c61d336885150ab0ad337fe6eaadcbc6ec514da8874b",
        "shares": 67039.31083319,
        "paid": 149.85049311,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          98640
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85049311
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 67039.31083319
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529028937339,
        "txid": "ee4d3d3ec4c08d64a378815727ae7044a1456e431a985bc55bc26daa5aee0223",
        "shares": 3104.29760367,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          97823
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 3104.29760367
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1529024137173,
        "txid": "c0451e2ad08a720f685ea7c522bf8d634b00e052e5895aa875b9b0feedc27348",
        "shares": 50725.214786690005,
        "paid": 149.84990226,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          97798
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84990226
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 50725.214786690005
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528938335048,
        "txid": "d7a2a8cc32c8d32ca099315ec1a0876217a4327f72c196924b0c1887c5fe7445",
        "shares": 26410.11564011,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          97096
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 26410.11564011
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528913134453,
        "txid": "4d5c9cc4ed088e3254392f323066ebda849a8a7e3f307e0e627d581c4c472d31",
        "shares": 40580.80231319,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96889
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 40580.80231319
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528868733295,
        "txid": "9ce3565134e056c92b0306df7be77e79199db2466a203327ed2d2e08bc9e235d",
        "shares": 6602.56576397,
        "paid": 149.85000464,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96520
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85000464
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 6602.56576397
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528865133212,
        "txid": "60e4d615ab23204ccef61609b228be1421e3ab649a1164ae50f060722b5c31dc",
        "shares": 6928.362205519999,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96461
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 6928.362205519999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528854933095,
        "txid": "eea83530e19e5c31263cfd79492a5af9102451c6b565916554e33fa187a67945",
        "shares": 21489.088447084003,
        "paid": 149.84999999,
        "miners": 2,
        "blocks": [
          96392
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 133.34363659,
          "t1N41CQNY7wnDAEjFCBtfRgASGHBc7XHnZU": 16.5063634
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 19122.01001398,
          "t1N41CQNY7wnDAEjFCBtfRgASGHBc7XHnZU": 2367.078433104
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528834954934,
        "txid": "f6d4eabe2a90545bddb96e687281144d956026a39519920a4b5a8b279de68fb2",
        "shares": 19609.1102692,
        "paid": 149.85045733,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96219
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85045733
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 19609.1102692
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528814554277,
        "txid": "802947af15e475deaed5afd2ff595b59bd17ae2166e70b6fa3a5b1e084d66595",
        "shares": 28021.99010114,
        "paid": 149.850106,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          96056
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.850106
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 28021.99010114
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528785753397,
        "txid": "bc2a1d4268dc5ea371b3190c3e491423f3f3ba3e90b97d4bd804ae8b7615f310",
        "shares": 92962.78615252,
        "paid": 149.85010001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          95827
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85010001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 92962.78615252
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528672350183,
        "txid": "c23a481796e55cd238e83a9f29e7f0e6d038ea2cc23c3f7f14f7cae89a0c678f",
        "shares": 2028.6092466999999,
        "paid": 149.85,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94888
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 2028.6092466999999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528669950113,
        "txid": "186bd6824fabb6afeec2f4d012b80d356f53dab33c04b5fdf9b6cc8f7d0c5820",
        "shares": 776.0212537699999,
        "paid": 149.85010001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94862
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85010001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 776.0212537699999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528668150031,
        "txid": "908c4fec156aa4551a42e05289ed0ed98838ff9fd7fba5c7d1246ec7d7087cac",
        "shares": 66284.28441329999,
        "paid": 149.84989999,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94858
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84989999
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 66284.28441329999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528599148167,
        "txid": "9e9da753d046924b182583b3ac65bf7059855a7c973ec1fd67d51ac13c048ea0",
        "shares": 1197.33956242,
        "paid": 149.84995666,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94274
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84995666
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 1197.33956242
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528596748331,
        "txid": "c5efb5e87443c17a8754ce5b9565e388062fe4c3b2040577bfcb5c2e309810b8",
        "shares": 21428.0708466,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94262
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 21428.0708466
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528572147403,
        "txid": "bd3f2b453f11b2065238f28f4240d4aa808d6504d6d95b03e73c64f9435cc0df",
        "shares": 9707.29130202,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          94055
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 9707.29130202
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528559547010,
        "txid": "d3d786138d1160ccd541193a30b5c1193c7891e0aaf6a2b9524d79e88ae135d9",
        "shares": 35197.046698520004,
        "paid": 149.85036822,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          93956
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85036822
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 35197.046698520004
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528526546074,
        "txid": "1d3b65c03eece5416b549aacd170f9fa4fa5c37bf96a418b01620398fc798554",
        "shares": 22786.8939854,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          93669
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 22786.8939854
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528502545384,
        "txid": "bc912683a05aac13c6e6f65b6b89bf51e66e072da6d5576c892ba40adc93d1f1",
        "shares": 19795.81189089,
        "paid": 149.85126176,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          93475
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85126176
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 19795.81189089
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528387342482,
        "txid": "f49a81c73629ee723c3c080e392c6273c3a010f1ff8b04cdfd4ffb1d6651ddb4",
        "shares": 13801.18398016,
        "paid": 149.85006379,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92525
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85006379
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 13801.18398016
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528373542146,
        "txid": "ab0f04fa27cf112827a647e81b9669370c91736ebbae24535c75885d2b847a9e",
        "shares": 36476.16667485,
        "paid": 149.85000001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92411
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85000001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 36476.16667485
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528337873333,
        "txid": "5153937d325780b3ed78fe38dd2bab02baefc55d23e049a994bbcd4da84c3b72",
        "shares": 940.4181375700001,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92107
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 940.4181375700001
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528335473504,
        "txid": "03e601161435ca1fa420ee042b589d11624a0e2ad3ff6a57eb95b77a1bd7169b",
        "shares": 13851.424451159999,
        "paid": 149.85,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          92092
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 13851.424451159999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528322272892,
        "txid": "ba6c268f93705e86d0a218c180b90600f6472539e52fda3a452fdfea0cf1a4c7",
        "shares": 82079.63046338,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          91973
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 82079.63046338
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528238870764,
        "txid": "7ca39936f3ff8fe53c2f79e21e34d7857adbaefc6e6d1af57cf1cca92957a114",
        "shares": 76737.7005630349,
        "paid": 149.84827801,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          91294
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84827801
        },
        "balances": {
          "t1WtvsMS53Hy2J2AmcnHBZwRVRZPEejmKYh": 0.00162199
        },
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 76736.86994562,
          "t1WtvsMS53Hy2J2AmcnHBZwRVRZPEejmKYh": 0.8306174149000043
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528157268659,
        "txid": "cb0e1868226c90efd00b5cd8fdff2e3b48ef27f07baac212e17e834a2f939977",
        "shares": 55456.70607415,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          90643
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 55456.70607415
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528090066808,
        "txid": "c122dbbbfca258a8dfe07dd685ffc13505a2e97334c56d564fe7b19cbd297121",
        "shares": 20286.36657748,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          90082
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 20286.36657748
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528066666230,
        "txid": "e081bd339f76e95f3fe637abc4b33694cfc7fd3bcf6cd3896a9d57972b2b2e4f",
        "shares": 12740.56517011,
        "paid": 149.84991112,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89883
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84991112
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 12740.56517011
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528046265763,
        "txid": "8155afb7fcd4b9f7a3e31d9621d833a2f27a00101834694fd17ed97d74ff4c3f",
        "shares": 10092.89574236,
        "paid": 149.85020001,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89730
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85020001
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 10092.89574236
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528034865459,
        "txid": "d801d78f370742ecab69107b10390b7c9982270eed84249bb75edd6771b17c48",
        "shares": 1080.43224556,
        "paid": 149.8504,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89631
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8504
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 1080.43224556
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528034265462,
        "txid": "c4675e5fafd08b81c9a5a2b8c29e90a396a36e9e8ed18e8c728e155d08e8b722",
        "shares": 17724.76201563,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89622
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 17724.76201563
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1528012664846,
        "txid": "465fbc8ced6bd1466c7bc18482ff265cfc508dd00deabf29db037290a14fed2c",
        "shares": 13233.20481279,
        "paid": 149.84997922,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89447
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.84997922
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 13233.20481279
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1527998264492,
        "txid": "6850c419e97170a4ff60ea7c564a33c726c6445b22434901b5d4cd5d2f3c23b8",
        "shares": 58721.78385429,
        "paid": 149.85027536,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          89312
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85027536
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 58721.78385429
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522691664138,
        "txid": "85723d60e454626ac1c7f1333a0d2e0073faba5588868eb87583e517890d8026",
        "shares": 1717.07527153,
        "paid": 149.850023,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          45397
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.850023
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 1717.07527153
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522688663809,
        "txid": "c0a05ef564b660355a7cedc41bb816c804ce6f77559c47fc668b8510ebe2bb17",
        "shares": 15514.524170879999,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          45368
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 15514.524170879999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522638303217,
        "txid": "24c0bfcb3c67a79cffd9830bebc524e50827dd4fefd7316ae26e479cdcea880a",
        "shares": 5678.853654129999,
        "paid": 149.8499,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          44665
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8499
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 5678.853654129999
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522604440745,
        "txid": "545feed0c5cb9f294ae260b9ec7e33cf5a5d814f32714d2bceb8fbc136f6d8be",
        "shares": 454.36380947,
        "paid": 149.8501,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          44581
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.8501
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 454.36380947
        }
      },
      {
        "time": 1522593827155,
        "txid": "3d6b8ca0d33d644d57a38196fe47d5da228a50061805499807ae311f84adf5c9",
        "shares": 10549.50725814,
        "paid": 149.85012367,
        "miners": 1,
        "blocks": [
          44575
        ],
        "amounts": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 149.85012367
        },
        "balances": {},
        "work": {
          "t1QATR1DnhnrKEsv3tUvWzcjFHKEV4GPBZU": 10549.50725814
        }
      }
    ]
  }]

var totalAmount =
  data[0].payments.
filter(payment => payment.time > Date.now() - 24*60*60*1000).
map(payment => payment.amounts). //get all amount object
map(amounts => amounts[addr]). //get amount from addr
filter(price => price). //filter undefined amount
reduce((first, second) => { //sum amount
  return first + second;
});
totalAmount = totalAmount.toFixed(5);
console.log(totalAmount)
```